# Twitter search API getting errors

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

I am trying to collect twitter search results.
I am using twitter search API with Nodejs.
Started with "quick start" given in twitter api site https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/recent-search/quick-start, but I am keeping get errors from my request.

this is my code:

```html
  
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request');
const util = require('util');

const get = util.promisify(request.get);
const post = util.promisify(request.post);

const consumer_key = 'xxxxxxx';                             // Add your API key here
const consumer_secret = 'xxxxxx'; // Add your API secret key here

const bearerTokenURL = new URL('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token');
const searchURL = new URL('https://api.twitter.com/labs/2/tweets/search');

async function bearerToken (auth) {
  const requestConfig = {
    url: bearerTokenURL,
    auth: {
      user: consumer_key,
      pass: consumer_secret,
    },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    },
  };

  const response = await post(requestConfig);
  return JSON.parse(response.body).access_token;
}

(async () => {
  let token;
  const query = 'obama';
  const maxResults = 10;

  try {
    // Exchange your credentials for a Bearer token
    token = await bearerToken({consumer_key, consumer_secret});
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Could not generate a Bearer token. Please check that your credentials are correct and that the Filtered Stream preview is enabled in your Labs dashboard. (${e})`);
    process.exit(-1);
  }

  const requestConfig = {
    url: searchURL,
    qs: {
      query: query,
      max_results: maxResults,
      format: 'compact',
    },
    auth: {
      bearer: token,
    },
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'LabsRecentSearchQuickStartJS',
    },
    json: true,
  };

  try {
    const res = await get(requestConfig);  
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res);
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      throw new Error(res.json);
      return;
    }

    console.log(res.json);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Could not get search results. An error occurred: ${e}`);
    process.exit(-1);
  }
})();
```

my error:

> body: {
>       errors: [ [Object] ],
>       title: 'Invalid Request',
>       detail: 'One or more parameters to your request was invalid.',
>       type: 'https://api.twitter.com/labs/2/problems/invalid-request'   },   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false } Could not get search results. An
>   error occurred: Error

Comment: Never include your consumer key and secret in code you post online. You should regenerate these in the Twitter Developer Dashboard now to avoid other people stealing and misusing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in this script which we need to fix. If you remove the line `format: 'compact',` then this will work - that parameter is no longer valid in Labs v2.

Comment: Worked!! but wht do this example exist in twitter "get started" example?

Comment: It's a mistake, and I've raised a ticket to get it fixed. Apologies for the frustration!